# Drawings flickering while drawing on SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, flicker

I can not solve flickering problem on surface view. I am drawing drawing on SurfaceView like on FingerPaint project. However double buffering on SurfaceView results flickering on view. I tried all solutions which answered before, but no luck. I also tried to set single bitmap on surface canvas but flickering does not gone. Here is code to draw :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c = null;
    while (_running) {
        try {

            c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (holder) {
                if (c == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                c.setBitmap(mBitmap);
                doDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        } 
   }
}

 private void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);

    }
 }
```

Any help kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I was drawing with finger at some places sometimes flickering was appearing. The reason was MainUiThread and SurfaceView's drawer thread were drawing the same object at the same time. That's why incorrect drawings appeared. After synchronizing objects problem gone.